# Не запускаеться VM (genymotion)

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, genymotion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

OS windows 10

IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

Check Enable Server.
Server Address: 192.168.56.100
Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

Hyper-V отключен

Не могу запустить емулятор

Log

VirtualBox VM 5.0.20 r106931 win.amd64 (Apr 28 2016 14:04:10) release log
00:00:00.423455 Log opened 2016-06-09T13:19:22.183596300Z
00:00:00.423457 Build Type: release
00:00:00.423461 OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:00.423462 OS Release: 10.0.10586
00:00:00.423463 OS Service Pack:
00:00:00.465962 DMI Product Name: GA-MA74GM-S2
00:00:00.472400 DMI Product Version:
00:00:00.472414 Host RAM: 4094MB total, 916MB available
00:00:00.472416 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
00:00:00.472417 Process ID: 6796
00:00:00.472417 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.497597 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:00.497676   None installed!
00:00:00.501847 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:00.694604 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0) at 0xfffff801e9910000 - ModuleInit at fffff801e992fb10 and ModuleTerm at fffff801e9930000 using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:00.694654 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at fffff801e9932a00 and VMMR0EntryFast at fffff801e9930730
00:00:00.694661 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0=0xfffff801e9910000
00:00:00.702152 Guest OS type: 'Linux'
00:00:00.711458 WARNING! 64-bit guest type selected but the host CPU does NOT support HW virtualization.
00:00:00.740204 File system of 'C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280\Snapshots' (snapshots) is ntfs
00:00:00.740224 File system of 'C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280\Snapshots/{db90d8db-1f35-4033-bcff-4239810af560}.vmdk' is ntfs
00:00:00.752476 File system of 'C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280\Snapshots/{344a47bb-c624-465e-a62f-7f9564ac76ae}.vmdk' is ntfs
00:00:00.764320 File system of 'C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280\Snapshots/{ab5162ae-8b41-44f0-9ebc-f85b8c310e55}.vdi' is ntfs
00:00:01.043359 Shared clipboard service loaded
00:00:01.043394 Shared clipboard mode: Off
00:00:01.051089 Drag and drop service loaded
00:00:01.051116 Drag and drop mode: Off
00:00:01.065845 Guest Control service loaded
00:00:01.836402 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
00:00:01.836405 [/] (level 0)
00:00:01.836407   CSAMEnabled        = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836409   CpuExecutionCap    = 0x0000000000000064 (100)
00:00:01.836411   EnablePAE          = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836413   HMEnabled          = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836414   MemBalloonSize     = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836415   Name                = "Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280" (cb=41)
00:00:01.836416   NumCPUs            = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836417   PATMEnabled        = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836418   PageFusionAllowed  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836419   RamHoleSize        = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:01.836421   RamSize            = 0x0000000080000000 (2 147 483 648, 2 048 MB)
00:00:01.836423   RawR0Enabled       = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836424   RawR3Enabled       = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836425   TimerMillies       = 0x000000000000000a (10)
00:00:01.836426   UUID                 = "3f d7 d8 7a d4 e7 60 42 b8 a0 89 b3 3f 37 87 fe" (cb=16)
00:00:01.836431
00:00:01.836431 [/CPUM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.836432   PortableCpuIdLevel  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836434
00:00:01.836434 [/DBGF/] (level 1)
00:00:01.836435   Path   = "C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 -   768x1280/debug/;C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280/;C:\Users\DanTaLioN/" (cb=238)
00:00:01.836437
00:00:01.836437 [/Devices/] (level 1)
00:00:01.836438
00:00:01.836439 [/Devices/8237A/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836440
00:00:01.836440 [/Devices/8237A/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836442   Trusted  = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836443
00:00:01.836443 [/Devices/VMMDev/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836444
00:00:01.836445 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836446   PCIBusNo       = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836447   PCIDeviceNo    = 0x0000000000000004 (4)
00:00:01.836448   PCIFunctionNo  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836449   Trusted        = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836450
00:00:01.836451 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836452   GuestCoreDumpDir   = "C:\Users\DanTaLioN\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280\Snapshots" (cb=115)
00:00:01.836454   RamSize           = 0x0000000080000000 (2 147 483 648, 2 048 MB)
00:00:01.836456
00:00:01.836456 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836458   Driver   = "HGCM" (cb=5)
00:00:01.836459
00:00:01.836459 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.836461   Object  = 0x000000000157fa00 (22 542 848)
00:00:01.836462
00:00:01.836462 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836464   Driver   = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:01.836465
00:00:01.836465 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.836467   First    = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836468   Last     = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836469   papLeds  = 0x000000000157f650 (22 541 904)
00:00:01.836470
00:00:01.836470 [/Devices/acpi/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836472
00:00:01.836472 [/Devices/acpi/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836474   PCIBusNo       = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836475   PCIDeviceNo    = 0x0000000000000007 (7)
00:00:01.836476   PCIFunctionNo  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836476   Trusted        = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836477
00:00:01.836478 [/Devices/acpi/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836480   CpuHotPlug           = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836481   FdcEnabled           = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836482   HostBusPciAddress    = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836483   HpetEnabled          = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836484   IOAPIC               = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836486   IocPciAddress        = 0x0000000000010000 (65 536)
00:00:01.836487   NumCPUs              = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836488   Parallel0IoPortBase  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836489   Parallel0Irq         = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836490   Parallel1IoPortBase  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836491   Parallel1Irq         = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836492   RamHoleSize          = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:01.836494   RamSize              = 0x0000000080000000 (2 147 483 648, 2 048 MB)
00:00:01.836495   Serial0IoPortBase    = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836496   Serial0Irq           = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836497   Serial1IoPortBase    = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836498   Serial1Irq           = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836499   ShowCpu              = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836500   ShowRtc              = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836501   SmcEnabled           = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836502
00:00:01.836503 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836504   Driver   = "ACPIHost" (cb=9)
00:00:01.836505
00:00:01.836506 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.836507
00:00:01.836508 [/Devices/apic/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836509
00:00:01.836509 [/Devices/apic/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836511   Trusted  = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836512
00:00:01.836512 [/Devices/apic/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836513   IOAPIC   = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836514   NumCPUs  = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836515
00:00:01.836516 [/Devices/e1000/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836517
00:00:01.836517 [/Devices/i8254/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836518
00:00:01.836519 [/Devices/i8254/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836520
00:00:01.836520 [/Devices/i8254/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836522
00:00:01.836522 [/Devices/i8259/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836523
00:00:01.836524 [/Devices/i8259/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836525   Trusted  = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.836526
00:00:01.836527 [/Devices/i8259/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.836528
00:00:01.836529 [/Devices/ichac97/] (level 2)
00:00:01.836530
00:00:01.836530 [/Devices/ichac97/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.836532   PCIBusNo       = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836533   PCIDeviceNo    = 0x0000000000000005 (5)
00:00:01.836534   PCIFunctionNo  = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.836534   Trusted        = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
...
00:00:01.836920 
00:00:01.836921 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************
00:00:01.836938 VM: fHMEnabled=true  (configured) fRecompileUser=false   fRecompileSupervisor=false
00:00:01.836940 VM: fRawRing1Enabled=false CSAM=true  PATM=true
00:00:01.837126 HM: HMR3Init: Falling back to raw-mode: AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS)
00:00:01.837179 MM: cbHyperHeap=0x140000 (1310720)
00:00:01.838037 CPUM: fXStateHostMask=0x0; initial: 0x0; host XCR0=0x0
00:00:01.838798 CPUM: Matched host CPU AMD 0x10/0x5/0x2 AMD_K10 with CPU DB     entry 'AMD Phenom II X6 1100T' (AMD 0x10/0xa/0x0 AMD_K10)
00:00:01.838863 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000017 IA32_PLATFORM_ID
00:00:01.838872 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x000001a0 IA32_MISC_ENABLE
00:00:01.838878 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x0000002c P4_EBC_FREQUENCY_ID
00:00:01.857054 PGM: HCPhysInterPD=00000000cfde3000   HCPhysInterPaePDPT=00000000cfde0000 HCPhysInterPaePML4=00000000cfdde000
00:00:01.857087 PGM: apInterPTs={00000000cfde2000,00000000cfde1000}   apInterPaePTs={000000007e09a000,00000000b764b000} apInterPaePDs=  {0000000064304000,00000000258ed000,0000000054f0e000,00000000601c7000}   pInterPaePDPT64=00000000cfddf000
00:00:01.857095 PGM: Host paging mode: AMD64+PGE+NX
00:00:01.857114 PGM: PGMPool: cMaxPages=1072 (u64MaxPages=1058)
00:00:01.857119 PGM: pgmR3PoolInit: cMaxPages=0x430 cMaxUsers=0x860   cMaxPhysExts=0x860 fCacheEnable=true
00:00:01.885556 TM: GIP - u32Mode=3 (Invariant) u32UpdateHz=93   u32UpdateIntervalNS=10741500 enmUseTscDelta=2 (Pratically Zero) fGetGipCpu=0x3 cCpus=4
00:00:01.885608 TM: GIP - u64CpuHz=2 907 209 596 (0xad487f7c)    SUPGetCpuHzFromGip => 2 907 209 596
00:00:01.885616 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x0 idCpu=0x0 idApic=0x0 iGipCpu=0x0   i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2907209596(*) cErrors=0

00:00:01.885622 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x1 idCpu=0x1 idApic=0x1 iGipCpu=0x3   i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2907209305(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.885628 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x2 idCpu=0x2 idApic=0x2 iGipCpu=0x1   i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2907229381(*) cErrors=0

00:00:01.885633 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x3 idCpu=0x3 idApic=0x3 iGipCpu=0x2   i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=2907205538(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.885702 TM: cTSCTicksPerSecond=2 907 209 596 (0xad487f7c) enmTSCMode=3   (Dynamic)
00:00:01.885704 TM: TSCTiedToExecution=false TSCNotTiedToHalt=false
00:00:01.886207 VMM: CoreCode: R3=00000000044c0000 R0=ffffd0010b66b000   RC=a0a67000 Phys=00000000cf40c000 cb=0x1000
00:00:01.888351 GIM: Using provider 'None' (Implementation version: 0)
00:00:01.888434 AIOMgr: Default manager type is 'Async'
00:00:01.888440 AIOMgr: Default file backend is 'NonBuffered'
00:00:01.888985 BlkCache: Cache successfully initialized. Cache size is 5242880 bytes
00:00:01.889016 BlkCache: Cache commit interval is 10000 ms
00:00:01.889021 BlkCache: Cache commit threshold is 2621440 bytes
00:00:02.038786 PcBios: [SMP] BIOS with 1 CPUs
00:00:02.038967 PcBios: MPS table at 000e1300
00:00:02.059666 SUP: Loaded VBoxDDR0.r0 (C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDDR0.r0) at 0xfffff801eb1f0000 - ModuleInit at 0000000000000000 and ModuleTerm at 0000000000000000 using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:02.059697 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDDR0.r0=0xfffff801eb1f0000
00:00:02.076043 SUP: Loaded VBoxDD2R0.r0 (C:\Program   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDD2R0.r0) at 0xfffff801eb260000 - ModuleInit at   0000000000000000 and ModuleTerm at 0000000000000000 using the native ring-0   loader
00:00:02.076066 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxDD2R0.r0=0xfffff801eb260000
00:00:02.076133 APIC: Activating Local APIC
00:00:02.076146 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled APIC
00:00:02.076624 PIT: mode=3 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:02.086824 Shared Folders service loaded
00:00:02.114162 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:02.114193 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:02.114580 VD: VDInit finished
00:00:02.141568 VD: Opening the disk took 27343710 ns
00:00:02.141728 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=1098/16/63, total number of sectors 1107630
00:00:02.141754 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:02.141759 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:02.169737 VD: Opening the disk took 27952014 ns
00:00:02.169890 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#1: disk, PCHS=11461/16/63, total number of   sectors 11552768
00:00:02.170001 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:02.170007 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:02.184319 VD: Opening the disk took 14284599 ns
00:00:02.184456 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#2: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 16777216
00:00:02.184474 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:02.184518 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:02.184555 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:02.184718 IntNet#0: szNetwork={HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter} enmTrunkType=3 szTrunk={\DEVICE{D62C7644-6509-457B-BAE9-D88923200202}} fFlags=0x8000 cbRecv=325632 cbSend=196608   fIgnoreConnectFailure=false
00:00:02.184794 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-  5.0\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DrvIntNet.cpp(1753) int __cdecl   drvR3IntNetConstruct(struct PDMDRVINS *,struct CFGMNODE *,unsigned int);   rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:02.184832 VMSetError: Failed to open/create the internal network   'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'
00:00:02.184886 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-  5.0\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DevVirtioNet.cpp(2082) int __cdecl   vnetConstruct(struct PDMDEVINS *,int,struct CFGMNODE *);   rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:02.184891 VMSetError: Failed to attach the network LUN
00:00:02.184906 PDM: Failed to construct 'virtio-net'/0!   VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND (-3600) - The networking interface to filter was not found.
00:00:02.294988 TxTimer stats (avg/min/max):       0 usec      -1 usec       0 usec
00:00:02.299219 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
00:00:02.299292 Failed to attach the network LUN   (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:02.299595 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:02.385885 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 00:00:01.837126 HM: HMR3Init: Falling back to raw-mode: AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS)

В BIOS'е включите виртуализацию.